# Getting the count of duplicate values in arrayList in Java without affecting the order of arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, find-occurrences

I am trying to get the count of duplicate values of `String ArrayList`, i have achieved the task but not completely. i am able to get the `counts` of duplicate `elements` of my `arrayList`, but the problem is that the `order` of `arrayList` destroys when i get the `occurrences` of `elements`

here is my `code`:

```
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String str : t.courseName) {
        if (counts.containsKey(str)) {
            counts.put(str, counts.get(str) + 1);
        } else {
            counts.put(str, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

this code works fine for getting `occurrences` but note that this code destroys the `order`. what i want is that the `order` should also not be destroyed.

Comment: If you are using java 8 your if-else statement can be simplified to `counts.merge(str, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of `HashMap` to preserve the insertion order

> A LinkedHashMap is a combination of hash table and linked list. It has a predictable iteration order (a la linked list), yet the retrieval speed is that of a HashMap. The order of the iteration is determined by the insertion order, so you will get the key/values back in the order that they were added to this Map.

Comment: thanks!! you saved my day!! it worked fine